# Ways to arrange letters of 'ANSWER' that do not end with R

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we start from the back, there are 5 ways to put the last letter, 5 ways to put the last second, 4 ways for last third and then 1 way for the first letter, i.e., 5 X 5 X 4 X 3 X 2 X 1, which is the answer.
But if I start from the front, the answer comes out to be zero.
6 ways to arrange first letter, 5 for second, till 2 for fifth, now R cannot be the last letter, so there must be 0 ways to arrange last letter. 
Where am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @Bram28 oh sorry. ty.

Comment: Starting from the front is a bad idea - you have to somehow condition on the basis of whether R has been chosen yet or not. The first method is fine though.

Comment: There are only zero ways to place the last letter if that letter is in fact $R$. Otherwise there is one way to place it. Since the last letter will be be $R$ only $1/6$ of the time, and $5/6$ of the time it will be something else, the two answers agree.

Answer (score 2):

When starting in the front, you can use R ... or not.  But it does not mean that when you get to the last letter you are left with R.  This is exactly why starting with the last letter is the better method to get the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to count this if you do want to start from the front is to just count all the possible ways to arrange the letters and then take away the number that have R as the final letter.

Counting all the ways to arrange the 6 letters gives you $6!$ or $6*5*4*3*2*1$. Exactly one sixth of these have R as the final letter (because there are 6 letters) so take $6! * 5/6$.

You can also check this gives you the same answer you got by working backwards because $$ 6! * 5/6 = 6 * 5! * 5/6 = 5!*5 = 5*5*4*3*2*1$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also think that R has to be in one of the first 5 spots. So there are 5 spots you could put that R, and then 5 letters to pick from to fill the first empty spot, 4 to fill the second, etc etc. So you end up with $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ which is the same answer obviously.